# Unable to correctly configure StrongSwan with site-to-site connection and road warrior

Tags: ip, vpn, ipsec, strongswan

I have the following config om my server

```
connections {

    mycompay-vpn {
        local_addrs = <MY_COMPANY_IP>
        version = 2
        pools = mycompay-vpn-pool
        proposals = aes256-sha256-modp2048
        local {
            auth = pubkey
            certs = mycompay-vpn-cert.pem
            id = <MY_COMPANY_IP>
        }
        remote {
            auth = eap-mschapv2
        }
        children {
            mycompay-vpn {
                local_ts = 0.0.0.0/0
                esp_proposals = aes256-sha256-modp2048
                ah_proposals = aes256-sha256-modp2048
                mode = tunnel
                start_action = start
                updown = /usr/libexec/strongswan/_updown iptables
            }
        }
    }

    mycompany-partner {
        version = 2
        mobike = no
        proposals = aes256-sha256-ecp384
        local_addrs = <MY_COMPANY_IP>
        remote_addrs = <PARTNER_IP>
        pools = mycompany-vpn-pool
        local {
            auth = psk
        }
        remote {
            auth = psk
        }
        children {
            mycompany-partner-prod {
                remote_ts = <PROXY_PROD_SUBNET>
                local_ts = <SUBNET_DIFFERENT_FROM_PARTNER>
                updown = /usr/libexec/strongswan/_updown iptables
                start_action = start
                ah_proposals = aes256-sha256-ecp384
                esp_proposals = aes256-sha256-ecp384
                dpd_action = restart
            }
        }
    }
}

pools {
    mycompany-vpn-pool {
        addrs = <SUBNETWORK_DIFFERENT_FROM_PARTNER> <
    }
}

secrets {
ike-mycompany-partner {
    id = <PARTNER_IP>
    secret = <PSK>
  }
  ike-mycompany-partner {
    id = <MY_COMPANY_IP>
    secret = <PSK>
  }
}
```

When I connect to the VPN I get assigned an IP my subnet and I can see it assigned to my interface connected to the internet.
A default route is added to table 220 that redirect all traffic to come from that IP
default via 192.168.1.254 dev wlp0s20f3 proto static src 172.23.127.1

And xfrm policies are added to route traffic correctly to the VPN server public address.

But when I try to telent IPs on the partner's network I get No route to host

Any idea what might cause this ?

Policies on the server seem to be set correctly two, and both VPNs seem to be up and running.